# C++ Initialize String Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to initialize an array on strings but there's an error. Note: this works for `int arrays`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string names[n];   //error here
}
```

Comment: This does not work for any type of array unless you use a language extension.

Comment: this is the error: Variable length array of non-POD element type 'string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `<vector>` header and use

```
vector<string> names( n );
```

if you want to keep your existing design.

However, with a `vector` you can use the `push_back` method to append new items (add them at the end). And then there's no point in requiring the user to specify a size. Instead, let the size of the vector after the last item has been appended, be your `n`.

Comment: Cheers and hth, do you see that the program is reading an input n? If you use a vector like that then how should we use the input n?

Comment: @pythonhiew, Exactly as what's shown in the answer. This creates a vector of size `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
string *names = new string[n];
```

Your method doesn't work because if you create an array the way you did (by instance), then you need to initialize it immediately as well like so:

```
string names[] = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
```

If you dynamically allocate your array, you can resize by de-allocating and re-allocating when needed.

Or you could just use a vector,your choice.

Comment: Dynamic allocation does not support resizing. It would have to be reallocated with a larger size.

Comment: By resizing I meant de-allocating and reallocating new memory.